# Internet Explorer not displaying button with relative positioning and floating correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, position

I'm using a jQuery plugin called Impromptu. It's basically a plugin for clean modal boxes. At the bottom of the modal box it has a bar for buttons, but later on in the code I've had to use some more JS to add an extra button on the fly, but positioned on the left. It looks fine in all browsers except from IE (not tested 6 or 8, but this problem arises in IE 7 and is fixed in 9).

See image here: http://screencast.com/t/g1EmKu2KqXfB

The button to the left has the same classes as the ones to the right, except two extra properties: `position:relative` and `float:left`. After the `div` which holds the buttons, I have added an extra `div` with `clear:left`, but this doesn't seem to affect anything.

The buttons themselves are simple `button` elements, the syntax is quite heavy. For example this is the HTML for the newly added (problematic) button:

```
<button value="next" onclick="somefunction()" id="jqi_state0_buttonNext" name="jqi_state0_buttonNext" class="dynamo_temp_button">Next Page</button>
```

`.dynamo_temp_button` is the class with the previously stated `position:relative` and `float:left`.

How can I make the button stay on the same line with the other buttons, but keep its position floating on the left?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rRFqv/

Comment: please make a fiddle, so we can see the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no floating on the 2 buttons on the right, and IE has trouble with aligning non-floated & floated

try this demo:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRFqv/2/)

```
div.jqi .jqibuttons{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    overflow: hidden; //added
}
div.jqi button{
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background-color: #2F6073;
    border: solid 1px #f4f4f4;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: none;
    float: right; //added
}
.dynamo_temp_button {
    position : relative;
    float : left!important; //added
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly in IE 7 so thanks. Will be testing in IE 6.